# How to optimize an O(N*M) to be O(n**2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I am trying to solve USACO's Milking Cows problem. The problem statement is here: https://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?S=milk2&a=n3lMlotUxJ1

Given a series of intervals in the form of a 2d array, I have to find the longest interval and the longest interval in which no milking was occurring.

Ex. Given the array `[[500,1200],[200,900],[100,1200]]`, the longest interval would be 1100 as there is continuous milking and the longest interval without milking would be 0 as there are no rest periods.

I have tried looking at whether utilizing a dictionary would decrease run times but I haven't had much success.

```
f = open('milk2.in', 'r')
w = open('milk2.out', 'w')

#getting the input
farmers = int(f.readline().strip())
schedule = []
for i in range(farmers):
    schedule.append(f.readline().strip().split())


#schedule = data
minvalue = 0
maxvalue = 0

#getting the minimums and maximums of the data 
for time in range(farmers):
    schedule[time][0] = int(schedule[time][0])
    schedule[time][1] = int(schedule[time][1])
    if (minvalue == 0):
        minvalue = schedule[time][0]
    if (maxvalue == 0):
        maxvalue = schedule[time][1]
    minvalue = min(schedule[time][0], minvalue)
    maxvalue = max(schedule[time][1], maxvalue)

filled_thistime = 0
filled_max = 0

empty_max = 0
empty_thistime = 0

#goes through all the possible items in between the minimum and the maximum
for point in range(minvalue, maxvalue):
    isfilled = False
    #goes through all the data for each point value in order to find the best values
    for check in range(farmers):
        if point >= schedule[check][0] and point < schedule[check][1]:
            filled_thistime += 1
            empty_thistime = 0
            isfilled = True
            break
    if isfilled == False:
        filled_thistime = 0
        empty_thistime += 1
    if (filled_max < filled_thistime) : 
        filled_max = filled_thistime 
    if (empty_max < empty_thistime) : 
        empty_max = empty_thistime 
print(filled_max)
print(empty_max)
if (filled_max < filled_thistime):
    filled_max = filled_thistime

w.write(str(filled_max) + " " + str(empty_max) + "\n")
f.close()
w.close()
```

The program works fine, but I need to decrease the time it takes to run.

Comment: That's not O(n^3), that's O(n + n^2) = O(n^2).

Comment: The outer loop isn't iterating over N, but is iterating over the range of all points between min and max.  the inner loop iterates over N.  So, it's (much worse) than N**2, and possibly worse than N**3 just because of the sheer number of points in the outer loop.

Comment: It's probably more like O(NxM) where M is max-min though.

Comment: Can you use numpy?

Comment: I tried sorting the initial array, and that brought down the time from 1.5 seconds for the large testcase to about .150 seconds. However, I am now getting the wrong answer for that testcase, so I have to debug.

Comment: This might be a better question for [codereview.se], that stack site is dedicated to helping optimize working code, while stackoverflow is more aimed at solving problems with non-working code

Comment: What are `N` and `M`? In a graph algorithm, `M` is the number of edges, which is indeed `O(N^2)`, making `O(N*M) = O(N^3)`. The reason for using two variables is to emphasize the fact that the complexity is tied to the edge density of the graph input itself, as opposed to an algorithm which might have `O(N^3)` complexity regardless of the number of edges.

Comment: this can be solved super quickly using a stack.

Comment: If the input with *n* intervals is sorted by either the start or end of the interval (it should be known which), it can be done in *O(n)*, otherwise the initial sorting will determine the time complexity: *O(nlogn)*.

Comment: @trincot It is possible to solve this with a single pass on the data even if it is unsorted. You just need to store a set of ranges and update them for each element.

Comment: @CMMCD, I checked your solution: it is *O(n²)*.

Comment: @trincot Having nested loops does not imply _O(n²).

Comment: @CMMCD, Sure, but it does when both your loops are *O(n)*.

Comment: @Krish, the link you provided asks for credentials, so it is not suitable here. Please provide all necessary information in your question. For instance, in your title you mentioned N and M. What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A less pretty but more efficient approach would be to solve this like a free list, though it is a bit more tricky since the ranges can overlap. This method only requires looping through the input list a single time.

```py
def insert(start, end):
    for existing in times:
        existing_start, existing_end = existing
        # New time is a subset of existing time
        if start >= existing_start and end <= existing_end:
            return
        # New time ends during existing time
        elif end >= existing_start and end <= existing_end:
            times.remove(existing)
            return insert(start, existing_end)
        # New time starts during existing time
        elif start >= existing_start and start <= existing_end:
            # existing[1] = max(existing_end, end)
            times.remove(existing)
            return insert(existing_start, end)
        # New time is superset of existing time
        elif start <= existing_start and end >= existing_end:
            times.remove(existing)
            return insert(start, end)
    times.append([start, end])

data = [
    [500,1200],
    [200,900],
    [100,1200] 
]

times = [data[0]]
for start, end in data[1:]:
    insert(start, end)

longest_milk = 0
longest_gap = 0
for i, time in enumerate(times):
    duration = time[1] - time[0]
    if duration > longest_milk:
        longest_milk = duration
    if i != len(times) - 1 and times[i+1][0] - times[i][1] > longest_gap:
        longes_gap = times[i+1][0] - times[i][1]

print(longest_milk, longest_gap)
```

Comment: This is not *O(n)*, since you have nested loops: `insert` is called in a loop, and `insert` itself has a loop. This is *O(n²)*.

Comment: `insert` only loops through a list of non overlapping time ranges so worst case this is _O(n*d)_  where n is the number of non overlapping ranges, correct? And we know that d can not be larger than 333k (since the max ending time is 1m) so we have _O(n*333k)_ -> _O(n)_

Comment: Well, assume the case where all input ranges are sorted ascendantly by their start element. So if *n* is the number of ranges you will then execute *n(n-1)/2* times `existing_end = existing`. If found overlapping, it could be you'd only find that overlap with the last collected range, so you'd still make all those iterations. Using the fact that there is an upper limit to *n* is not very useful, as time complexity only makes sense when *n* is unbounded, so then we might as well ditch the question about time complexity optimisation.

Comment: Within the problem definition this solution is _O(n)_ using the fact we have a maximum second delay of 1m. The limit on _n_ is not important, if you remove the limit on _n_ entirely this solution will still be _O(n)_ because the input range is limited.

Comment: I can only repeat what I said above.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, if the input is sorted, the complexity could be O(n), if that's not the case we need to sort it first and the complexity is O(nlog n):

```
lst = [ [300,1000],
[700,1200],
[1500,2100] ]

from itertools import groupby

longest_milking = 0
longest_idle = 0

l = sorted(lst, key=lambda k: k[0])

for v, g in groupby(zip(l[::1], l[1::1]), lambda k: k[1][0] <= k[0][1]):
    l = [*g][0]
    if v:
        mn, mx = min(i[0] for i in l), max(i[1] for i in l)
        if mx-mn > longest_milking:
            longest_milking = mx-mn
    else:
        mx = max((i2[0] - i1[1] for i1, i2 in zip(l[::1], l[1::1])))
        if mx > longest_idle:
            longest_idle = mx

# corner case, N=1 (only one interval)
if len(lst) == 1:
    longest_milking = lst[0][1] - lst[0][0]

print(longest_milking)
print(longest_idle)
```

Prints:

```
900
300
```

For input:

```
lst = [ [500,1200],
        [200,900],
        [100,1200] ]
```

Prints:

```
1100
0
```